# How to use curl grep to get html content?

Tags: html, regex, curl, grep

```
  #!/bin/sh
  page=`curl -sL xxx.com`
  url=`$page | grep -q "http:\/\/(\w.*?)\/"`
  echo $url
  echo $?
```

There is my bash. But it out:

```
line 3: <html><head><title>??????????⹤??</title></head><body><iframe: No such file or directory

0
```

How to solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `No such file or directory` error occurs since you try to execute the result of `curl -sL xxx.com` directly. I think what you desired is to use `grep` to process the result of it. One option is `echo $page` and feeds it to `grep` for processing.

And there are two options need to be added for `grep`, so modify your `url` to,

```
url=`echo $page | grep -oP "http:\/\/(\w.*?)\/"`
```

Brief explanation,

- `-P`: Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression since `\w` included in the pattern
- `-o`: only extract the pattern that match the Perl regex
- `-q`: no need to adopt `-q` since the output would be suppressed, that's why you get nothing for your `$url`